# Get first three child elements of parent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the first 3 elements in a div, so e1, e2 and e3:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="e1">element 1</div>
    <div id="e2">element 2</div>
    <div id="e3">element 3</div>
    <div id="e4">element 4</div>
</div>
```

I want to do this with jQuery. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `$('#parent').children().slice(0, 3).map(it => it.id)`

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually **you can do this with [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class** with functional notation. So this will work like:

```
:nth-child(-n+3)
Represents the first three elements. [=-0+3, -1+3, -2+3]
```

> Where the functional notation represents elements in a list whose indices match those found in a custom pattern of numbers, defined by `An+B`, where:
>   `A` is an integer step size,
>   `B` is an integer offset,
>   `n` is all positive integers, starting from `0`.

So your final code would be something like:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div:nth-child(-n+3)')

elements.forEach(element => {
   console.log(element.id)
})
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="e1">element 1</div>
  <div id="e2">element 2</div>
  <div id="e3">element 3</div>
  <div id="e4">element 4</div>
</div>
```

---

But **if you want to stick with jQuery itself you can use [jQuery `:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** instead. Where `jQuery( ":lt(index)" )` *Select all elements at an index less than `index` within the matched set*

The output will be something like this:

```js
const elements = $('#parent > div:lt(3)')

jQuery.each(elements, function (index, element) {
    console.log(element.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="e1">element 1</div>
  <div id="e2">element 2</div>
  <div id="e3">element 3</div>
  <div id="e4">element 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, however serial downvoting my recent answers, I don't have a problem with that but at least make a clarification for it and tell me why? :D

Comment: Works great, and a nice explanation! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function and a little conditional if statement with the function's index...

```
 $('#parent').children().each(function(index){
  // To counteract the zero-based index.
  index++
  if (index < 4) {
    console.log(this);
  }
});
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/ycodetech/pen/GRpwQwX?editors=1010)